# Query works without destination table, but fails with destination table "resources exceeded"

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query which produces about 20 million rows, which need to be ordered by timestamp DESC. When I use the setting "Save query results in a temporary table" then the query works, but when I set a destination table, then the query fails with the error "Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 126% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): ORDER BY operations: 97% other/unattributed: 3%".
I don't want to set a limit because I need all output rows to continue my analysis. What's the difference between the temporary table and the destination table. Why does one work and one doesn't. Finally, how can I fix this problem? The only way I can think of is to reduce the number of rows, so basically break it down into multiple "same" queries that fetch partitions of the final result, but that would increase my cost by about 5-10 times.

Comment: You want to sort 20 million rows? Why? What's the next step after the 20 million rows are sorted? Or would it be enough to get just the top 2000 rows?

Comment: Each row represents an action, I sort them (most recent first) and then take them over to another server for processing in that sorted order. There's a process that needs to be applied to each row, so no more aggregations happening. It's important we process them in this order. Some rows don't have timestamps (NULL), so in the end I have a couple of million rows with timestamps sorted newest to oldest and then all the others just after that, not sure how NULL rows are treated while sorting.

Comment: Good tip with looking at the next step. I realised I break them up into different action types. So I found a solution where I group by action type (I have less than 1000 of those) and then use ARRAY_AGG with ORDER BY timestamp on the rest of the row. Then I end up with huge rows (UI gives me "API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table") but I can use the result.

Comment: Saving ordered result into destination table has no sense and/or any practical value - because tables in BigQuery have no notion of physical order at all. So if you then pass it (anyhow) to "another server for processing" that order is lost and you need to order again anyway. so simple advise  - just drop your sort statement when you save result - and move that sorting to further processing phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments as answer:

- You really don't want to sort 20 million rows, and then put them back on BigQuery as a table. There's not much benefit of doing this.
- What you really want is to sort rows by each activation type. A solution for this is to use `ARRAY_AGG()`, and also `OVER(PARTITION BY)`.
- As an alternative that will keep your data sorted for the whole table: Use `CLUSTERING BY`. Then all your queries will only query that portion of the data.

See:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b